# iOS - Automatically Have Keyboard Toggled On ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I have a view in my app where the user has to enter information in a textfield. Instead of them clicking into the text field and toggling the keyboard, I would like to have the textfield already editable with the keyboard preloaded there so the user can immediately start typing. Surprisingly, I couldn't find any resources that preload the keyboard when a view controller is reached.

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the `ViewDidAppear:`

```
[yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Using `viewWillAppear:` might be better.

Comment: It's either one. Not much difference. If you have a lot of calculation or process on the viewWillAppear: I don't recommend that

Comment: It's up to the needs of the OP. Using `viewWillAppear:` means the keyboard will already be in view when the view controller appears. Using `viewDidAppear:` means the user will see the keyboard slide into place after the view controller appears.

Comment: This worked great, thanks! I put it in my viewWillAppear because my view was glitching whenever the keyboard would be toggled on and off.